# Problem loading Google App Scripts Library - get unknown function error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add libraries to my google sheets script. I can add them, but trying to use them in my sheets, I get an "unknown function" error.

For example, in my project's app script, I've added LodashGS v6. I can click on the library options and select 'open in a new tab' and can see the library's functions, in this case, LodashGS has a function called load, which loads the full lodash library. When I use LodashGS in the sheets, I get the "unknown function" error.

I've added `const _ = LodashGS.load();` into the Code.gs file, which should give me access to the underscore in my sheets. But using the _ will give the the same error.

How can I access these libraries.  I feel like I'm missing a minor detail but can't see to find it.

Here's a link to the google sheet I'm using - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vCkvohhecgSNEt5ybznDIRyzT70lDLz3TWxU-i2VwgQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You cannot use Apps Script methods (including from imported libraries) directly as [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). You have to define a function in Apps Script in order to use it as a custom function.

Also, you can access `functions`, not `variables`. For example, when doing `const _ = LodashGS.load();`, `_` is a variable (actually a constant! But the point remains) and cannot be used as a custom function. Hence, `_.now()` is not recognized.

Custom function are actually strict with the function syntax used. As you can see [in the naming guidelines](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#guidelines_for_custom_functions):

> The name of a custom function must be declared with the syntax `function myFunction()`, not `var myFunction = new Function()`.

(Arrow function syntax apparently is also allowed, so this documentation could arguably be updated, but the main point remains).

#### Solution:

Wrap your methods inside a function if you want to use it as a custom function. You can either use the `function` keyword, as you already did for `getTime()`, or [arrow functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#arrow_functions), for example:

```
const getTime = () => LodashGS.load().now();
```

#### Note:

Please take into account that the name of a custom function cannot end with an underscore (`_`) (see the previously referenced naming guidelines).